# How to track users on my website?

Tags: php, analytics, tracking, user-tracking

so I have a shopify website. And shopify sometimes give me a visitor log kind of like this:

"A user from  has visited your website,
First page visited: homepage (22 seconds)
About us (1 minute)
Product page (2 minutes)"

I was wondering how I would go about creating something similar to this in php/js.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to do this client side. PHP has no way of knowing when a window is closed, it is only on the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use Google Analytics, it has in depth analytics on visitors. Its just about embedding JS code in your page and you're good to go. If you build your own code in any language, I'm pretty sure you will end up writing tonnes of codes.

To answer your question,

1.Create a web socket connection from your page to backend.

2.Pass event codes like clicks, refresh, session ids etc on user actions. Your JS can fire them up with an active web socket connection. It is pretty much light weight.

To store this information, I would suggest to use NoSql.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know google analytics has these features, but I was just wondering how to go about this because to me it's a fun thing to try out. *edit* thanks I'll try it out :)